# Error while exporting zipped files from R linux server

Tags: r, linux, download, system

I get the following R code execution error when I try to export and download zipped files from the R Linux server to my computer even though I have the zip and unzip files installed.

```
   Error in system(createZipCommand, intern = TRUE) : 
  error in running command
```

Have anyone come across something similar and how did you solve it?

many Thanks
RJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what's going on here. It appears that the PATH definition (echo $PATH) got corrupted. This was also preventing me from installing and updating packages.
I updated the path-definition in the '.Renviron' file as below

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

Saved this new '.Reviron' file in the home folder, logged off from R Studio, and signed back in. Everything seems to be fine now.